# Multiple NSImages in NSView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is it possible to draw multiple `NSImages` in a single `NSView`?

So far drawing in an `NSView` subclass is done like so:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [image drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f) fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0f];
}

//to change the current image
- (void)newImage:(NSImage *)image_
{
     [image release];
     image = [image_ retain];
     [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

But this is for drawing just one image. Can anyone please help out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep references to the images you need to draw.

```
@interface MyView : NSView
{
    NSMutableArray* images;
}
```

Then, add the images with a suitable API, for example:

```
@implementation MyView

- (void) addImage: (NSImage *) anImage
{
    [images addObject: anImage];
    [self setNeedsDisplay: YES];
}
```

In `drawRect:` you can iterate through the `images` and draw all/some of them.